# R Package IBrokers placeOrder() function fails

Tags: r, ibrokers

I'm using the package: `IBrokers`. It works well for me when I request historical data. Also the call to `reqAccountUpdates()` works well.

I am having problems with this script:

```
# myscript.r

.libPaths("rpackages")
library(IBrokers)
tws2 = twsConnect(2)
print('Attempting BUY')
mytkr     = twsFuture("ES","GLOBEX","201412")
myorderid = sample(1001:3001, 1)
IBrokers:::.placeOrder(tws2, mytkr, twsOrder(myorderid, "BUY", "1", "MKT"))
twsDisconnect(tws2)
```

Sometimes the above script works okay. Usually though it fails. When it fails, it seems to connect okay.

Then I see this in my TWS console:

```
03:47:45:581 JTS-EServerSocket-290: [2:47:71:1:0:0:0:ERR] Message type -1.  Socket I/O error - 
03:47:45:581 JTS-EServerSocket-290: Anticipated error
jextend.d: Socket I/O error - 
    at jextend.sc.b(sc.java:364)
    at jextend.ch.sb(ch.java:1534)
    at jextend.ch.run(ch.java:1390)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at jextend.xh.d(xh.java:45)
    at jextend.sc.c(sc.java:579)
    at jextend.sc.r(sc.java:227)
    at jextend.af.a(af.java:232)
    at jextend.sc.f(sc.java:650)
    at jextend.pd.a(pd.java:822)
    at jextend.sc.b(sc.java:358)
    ... 3 more
03:47:45:583 JTS-EServerSocket-290: [2:47:71:1:0:0:0:ERR] Socket connection for client{2} has closed. 
03:47:45:583 JTS-EWriter14-291: [2:47:71:1:0:0:0:ERR] Unable write to socket client{2} - 
03:47:45:584 JTS-EServerSocketNotifier-288: Terminating
```

Can you offer any ideas on how you would wrestle with this issue?

One other piece of info:

I think the call to `reqIds()` may be necessary. Sometimes `reqIds()` would return an id not high enough. Then, I'd use it and `placeOrder()` would fail. So, I call `reqIds()` but then use `Sys.time()` to give me an id which is larger than the last ID I used.

Another problem may have been some code-text I copied out of a PowerPoint. Some of the code-characters may have been corrupt.

Comment: Can you answer your own question, rather than editing the answer into the question? (I don't remember if your current reputation level prohibits you from doing so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was orderid.

I need to be careful how I generate orderid.

Also I may have moused in bad characters from a powerpoint preso which had an example.

I posted some code which works in a comment in this thread.

Dan

Comment: That code should be posted in this answer, not in the question.  And this is not a forum.